# Dutch national flag on a Turing Machine

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, turing-machines

I have a sequence of characters xxxxxx (with x^k and k > 0)
My goal is to transform this sentence into a dutch flag, that is to say :

xxxxx -> RRWWBB
xxxx -> RWBB

with R <= W <= B

All solutions that I have found, have a very high complexity.
Do you have any hint/clue to help to me build a Turing machine using only one tape and one head/cursor?

Comment: Why xxxxx (5 x's) becomes RRWWBB (6 letters)?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_national_flag_problem

Comment: I have read lots of algorithms but they assume that the initial tape has already the letters (in a wrong order), which is not my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about dividing the task into subtasks like:

1. Change the last X to B.

   Change the last X to W.

   Change the first X to R.

   Change BW to WB.

**EDIT:**

Here's another approach: you say you've seen algorithms that start with the colors present (out of order). So all you really need is a way to put the colors in (out of order)...

Comment: I don't understand how to use it :

xxxx
xxxB
xxWB
RxWB ?

Comment: @user32617: So far, so good. What's next? (You said you wanted a hint.)